# Using Kerberos ticket authentication on a website?

Tags: kerberos, spnego

My office uses a local Kerberos client that we log into and create a local ticket.  I am wondering if it is possible to have this forwarded to a website?  I think I'm misunderstanding how some of this fits together.

I have read that Chrome has some sort of Kerberos ticket forwarding AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist:
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

but I can't find how that works.  Is the local ticket forwarded upon some request?

Could I have something like Apache ask to authenticate with the ticket and provide it the server to authenticate against, and then my code (via a cookie or something?) would have access to the authenticated ticket and the username?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist flag in Chrome is a way to specify which webservers should be allowed to delegate Kerberos tickets. By default this privilege is not granted. Allowing delegation means allowing Kerberos authentication between the webserver and deeper layers (for example database). In such scenario:

1. Chrome uses Kerberos to login in webserver
2. Webserver uses Kerberos to login in database (possible only if you allow webserver to use Kerberos here, i.e. only if you list this webserver in flag AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist in Chrome)